# reset object order javascript

Tags: javascript, object, reset

I have a object like this

```
{ 
   "items":{ 
      "2":{ 
         "id":122,
         "product_id":"DE",
         "price":"9.35",
      },
      "4":{ 
         "id":15,
         "product_id":"CH",
         "price":"8.00",
      }
     "7":{ 
         "id":78,
         "product_id":"CH",
         "price":"3.00",
      }
   },
   "total_price":"20.35",
   "item_count":2,
   "unit":"CHF"
}
```

Do you know how i reset the items order.

now 2, 4, 7

should be 0, 1, 2

Comment: Why don't you use an array?

Comment: Object properties do not have order. I assume you want to re-name the properties, counting up from 0, but have the property values keep their original relative key-name ordering? (So the property with the smallest name is renamed to `0`, the next-lowest is `1`, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0jocxj1b/2/) that shows you a way.

Im using a custom `format` function:

```
function format(object) {
    var items = {};

    var i = 0;
    for (var index in object.items) {
        items[i] = object.items[index];
        i++;
    }

    object.items = items;
}
```

The resulted object is this:

```
{
    "items": {
        "0": {
            "id": 122,
            "product_id": "DE",
            "price": "9.35"
        },
        "1": {
            "id": 15,
            "product_id": "CH",
            "price": "8.00"
        },
        "2": {
            "id": 78,
            "product_id": "CH",
            "price": "3.00"
        }
    },
    "total_price": "20.35",
    "item_count": 2,
    "unit": "CHF"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
var obj = {
  "items":{
     "2":{
        "id":122,
        "product_id":"DE",
        "price":"9.35",
     },
     "4":{
        "id":15,
        "product_id":"CH",
        "price":"8.00",
     },
    "7":{
        "id":78,
        "product_id":"CH",
        "price":"3.00",
     }
  },
  "total_price":"20.35",
  "item_count":2,
  "unit":"CHF"
}
var keys = Object.keys(obj.items)

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
   obj.items[i] = obj.items[keys[i]];
   delete obj.items[keys[i]];
};

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Object properties do not have order. I assume you want to re-name the properties, counting up from 0, but have the properties maintain the original relative ordering of their keys. (So the property with the smallest name is renamed to `0`, the second-to-smallest is `1`, etc.)

To do this, get all the property names, and sort the names numerically. Then, get all the values in the same over as their sorted property names. Finally, re-insert those property values with their new property names.

```
var itemsObj = obj["items"];

// get all names
var propertyNames = Object.keys(itemsObj);

// sort property names in numeric order: ["2", "4", "7"]
propertyNames.sort(function(a,b){ return a-b; });

// get property values, sorted by their property names
// ["2", "4", "7"] becomes [{ "id":122, .. }, { "id":15, ... }, { "id":78, ... }]
var values = propertyNames.map(function(propName) { return itemsObj[propName]; }

// clear out old property and add new property
for(var i=0; i<values.length; ++i) {
    delete itemsObj[propertyNames[i]];
    itemsObj[i] = values[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
    "items": {
        "2": {
            "id": 122,
            "product_id": "DE",
            "price": "9.35",
        },
        "4": {
            "id": 15,
            "product_id": "CH",
            "price": "8.00",
        },
        "7": {
            "id": 78,
            "product_id": "CH",
            "price": "3.00",
        }
    },
    "total_price": "20.35",
    "item_count": 2,
    "unit": "CHF"
};
var indices = Object.keys(data.items).map(function(i) { return parseInt(i, 10); }),
    counter = 0;

indices.sort();
indices.forEach(function (i) {
    if (i > counter) { // put here some more collision detecting!
        data.items[counter] = data.items[i];
        delete data.items[i];
        counter++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Aww man, I saw the `.map(parseInt)` too and thought I learned something exciting.

Answer (score 0):

Object properties order is not guaranteed anyway. You should use an array instead.

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/299843)